# Will be done this way/ in this way?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Look at this sentence:

> - next, we explain why the problem will be done **this** **way**.

Could we write the sentence adding the preposition "in" to?

Comment: To do a problem does not make sense unless you mean to do a math problem. Then, it's to do a problem this way.  Otherwise, to solve a problem ***in*** this way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i saw this sentence in a mathematic book. I want to know when to use "this way and in this way" and which one is. Correct. @lambie

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both ways are fine. (math context)

> Next, we explain why the problem will be done **in** this way.

This would be considered more formal. However, the *in* can be implied as in your example, thinking of it as follows. ( ) adds implied information.

> Next, we explain why the problem will be done. **(How?)** This way.

Comment: How do you do this math problem? Answer: Do it this way. [as the person answering writes on a screen or sheet of paper]. Do it "in this way" would be incorrect  here. However, one does solve a problem in this, that or some way.